# Copy text over another text

Tags: jquery, replace, append, clone

I want my categorySidebarLabelSelected to replace the text inside of areaTitle but not move it, I have tried .html which moves it, I have tried append which moves it, I did .clone but it created 2 links. Ive exhausted my attempts. here is my jquery.

```
$(".areaTitle").html($( ".categorySidebarLabelSelected").html(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('categorySidebarLabelSelected')
  }
    )).show();
   };

HTML CODE ADDED

 <td class="categorySidebarLabelLevel1 categorySidebarLabel" width="100%">
       <a class="categorySidebarLabelLevel1 categorySidebarLabel" title="" href="UserContentStart.aspx?category=6">MENU</a>
 </td>

  <div class="areaTitle" style="display: block;">
    </div>
```

I want MENU that is in my vertical menu to be placed inside of areaTitle as well (as the header so people know where they are)

Comment: What do you mean by *moves it*? Where does it move to?

Comment: What do you mean by "move it"

Comment: `I want ... to replace the text ... but not move it.` This sounds strange. Could you specify what exactly you mean.

Comment: When I do append, it removes the text from my vertical menu and places it inside of my .areaTitle i want to duplicate the text in categorySidebarLabelSelected to .areaTitle

Comment: Where is this .categorySidebarLabelSelected  in your HTML??

Answer (score 0):

Try this - but I dont' see anything in your html that has `class=categorySidebarLabelSelected`

```
// changes .areaTitle's text to same as .categorySidebarLabel's text
$(".areaTitle").text($("a.categorySidebarLabel").text());
```

Comment: Ok i got it, you both were right, the issue was I needed to add A after .categorySidebarLabelSelected. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(".areaTitle")
             .text($("td.categorySidebarLabel  a.categorySidebarLabel").text());
```